# Редирект в WordPress (REST API)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess

Здравствуйтe. Есть плагин обратной связи для WordPress «MetForm», который отправляет форму без перезагрузки страницы (через REST API) по данному маршруту:

```
/wp-json/metform/v1/entries/insert/
```

Как сделать редирект текущей страницы, если идёт POST-запрос к данному маршруту?

Т.е. работать это должно следующим образом:

1. Вы находитесь на странице `example.com/contact` с формой обратной связи.
2. Вы заполняете поля и нажимаете «Отправить».
3. Вас редиректит на страницу `example.com/success`

Задам глупый вопрос. Это нельзя реализовать через RewriteRule? Если нет, то, может быть, есть какие-то хуки, которые помогут реализовать данный редирект?

ОБНОВЛЕНО. Делал разные попытки, но результат один и тот же: происходит редирект самого роута, а не страницы с формой: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy8Bs.png

Т.е. вместо `example.com/contact` -> `example.com/success` происходит `/wp-json/metform/v1/entries/insert/` -> `/success`

Answer (score 1):

В методе обработки REST запроса `\WP_REST_Server::respond_to_request` есть фильтр

```
$response = apply_filters( 'rest_request_after_callbacks', $response, $handler, $request );
```

Он выполняется после того, как плагин выполнил все действия по обработке формы.

Можно попробовать подключить свой хук к этому фильтру, проанализировать в нём response, убедиться, что он идёт от нужного вам плагина и формы, и вызвать в нём `wp_safe_redirect` и `exit`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Ваш код работает, но он редиректит сам роут, а не страницу с формой. Вот текущий результат: https://i.imgur.com/BaYqMRi.png

Comment: А, ну да(( Тогда js перехватывать возврат из rest и перенаправить из js

Comment: а Вы не можете добавить в своё сообщение данный JS код, который делает редирект в случае ответа `200 OK` от данного роута?

Comment: Завтра попробую. Я не у компьютера и не смогу сегодня